# How to solve Facebook Error 191 without having a website?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, javafx, javafx-webengine

Me an my team are currently working on a software project at university and my present task is to bind our desktop javafx application with Facebook.

Basically I have an fxml method in a controller that is called when the user hits a "Share" button in my GUI. In the method I'd like to simply open up my .html file using a WebView:

```
@FXML
public void shareFacebookClicked() throws Exception{
    // Setting up the webview
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Read the html file and let the web engine load it.
    File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("facebook.html").toURI().getPath());
    webEngine.load(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.initOwner(this.stage);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(webView, 1000, 800));
    stage.show();
}
```

There is no problem with it, my "facebook.html" file is loaded and displayed correctly (well, almost correctly) in a web view.

The actual problem is that I'm constantly getting the 191 Facebook error saying that the link is not owned by the application. Since there are tons of posts and questions on this around the Internet (and yes I checked and read all of them) here are the things that I'm already aware of:

- I registered my application on the Facebook Developer site. I know about the AppID and Secret
- I know that this error mainly comes from the fact that people forget to set their website URL and domain in the Settings. **The problem is that I don't have a website. I just have a simple .html file which I'd like to use in a web view inside of javafx.** However, I tried all possible combinations advised on stackoverflow, facebook help centre and other forums which include: Setting website URL to http://localhost/, domain to localhost, enabling Embedded browser OAuth Login, setting the redirect URI to localhost too, etc.
- I assume that my goal could be achieved by using RESTfb, Facebook4j or Graph API. When I tried those I had to stop because I faced problems with the user authentication plus I thought this current option would be the easiest way (considering this feature has LOW-priority in our software).

None of this solved my problem therefore I've given up researching the answer and decided to post my very own personal question.
In my opinion there must be some error in the .html file and/or I completely misunderstand something in the way this works. The .html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
        <title> Share on Facebook </title>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
              $('#shareonfacebook').click(function (e) {
                    FB.ui({
                          appId: 'MY_APP_ID',
                          display: "popup",
                          method: "feed",
                          name: "Test",
                          link:"",
                          caption:"Test",
                          description: "Test",
                    });
              });
        });
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
       <div id="fb-root"></div>
       <button id="shareonfacebook" >Share</button>
        <script>
              FB.init({
                    appId : 'MY_APP_ID'
              });
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Partially I have this code from a tutorial site. Theoretically it should work. **All I want is a dialog to come up where the user can publish the results of the workout he/she completed using our software.** Currently when the .html file is opened up there is a simple button to click. This and all the "Test" strings inside of the javascript are only for testing. I just want to achieve that I can post something on my wall. The next step would be of course to somehow set the posting text dynamically etc.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong or how I should approach the whole thing. Like I said, the task is minimal therefore it shouldn't be that difficult but I've been sitting in front of my laptop for 2 days without any success. I'm ready to post more code or give more information if it's needed.

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: The Facebook JS SDK’s _intended purpose_ is use on websites, not within webviews in desktop apps. Frankly, I am not sure if what you are trying to do is supposed to work at all – I rather doubt it.

Comment: Btw., putting your app id into the `FB.ui` parameters makes no sense – that parameter belongs into the _intitialization method_ call, not into `FB.ui`.

Comment: In such a situation, I would try with the [URL-redirect version of the Share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#redirect) instead.

Comment: @CBroe first, thanks for your reply! I tried the URL redirection but the problem is actually still the same: whatever link i use in the redirection (or in the javascript above) it keeps saying that the application does not own the link -> error. :(

Comment: You need a website platform set up for the `redirect_uri` parameter of the Share dialog to point to. If `http://localhost/` doesn’t work for that (it usually does for me when testing apps, but those are actual web apps), then your only option is to have the `redirect_uri` point to `https://www.facebook.com/` instead (instead of setting up a website platform) – then that page will be redirected to after the user has shared the post.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you very much! I've finally managed to make it work with your help! Unfortunately there's no way to say that the redirect link should close the window but now I'll leave it simply either on localhost or facebook.com. Thanks again! :)